# Numpy filter 2D array by two masks

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D array and two masks, one for columns, and one for rows. If I try to simply do `data[row_mask,col_mask]`, I get an error saying `shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes ...`. On the other hand, `data[row_mask][:,col_mask]` works, but is not as pretty. Why does it expect indexing arrays to be of the same shape?

Here's a specific example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
row_mask = np.array([True, True, False, True])
col_mask = np.array([True, True, False])
print(data[row_mask][:,col_mask]) # works
print(data[row_mask,col_mask]) # error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ix_` function :

```
>>> data[np.ix_(row_mask,col_mask)]
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 4,  5],
       [10, 11]])
```

> Combining multiple Boolean indexing arrays or a Boolean with an integer indexing array can best be understood with the [obj.nonzero()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nonzero.html#numpy.ndarray.nonzero) analogy. The function [ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) also supports boolean arrays and will work without any surprises.

Comment: Thanks, just found the same answer.