# How to get the number of unique area within a kernel in connected component labeled map using python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to get the number of area in connected component labeled map.
For example:

```
[Image value]  
00011100022200   
00011000002220  
00000033300220  
44000033000020  
44000000000000
```

And if kernel size is 3x3, I would like to get the number of unique value in a same size 2D array.

For example, new 2D array has following value:

```
newarray[3,3]=2  
newarray[2,4]=1  
newarray[2,2]=0
```

I am working with Python, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with `numpy`, which has a nice syntax for [getting submatrices from a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297033/numpy-filter-2d-array-by-two-masks).

Let's assume we have the input data:

```
101
200
000
```

You can define this in numpy and retrieve the top-left 2x2-submatrix:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,0,1],[2,0,0],[0,0,0]])
submatrix = data[0:2,0:2]
```

Your kernel function seems to be "number of unique values not equal to zero in kernel area". This can be calculated with standard python functions:

```
values = list(submatrix.flatten())
without_zeros = list(filter(None, values))
unique_values_not_zero = set(without_zeros)
```

From here, you should be able to continue again. Here is a list of the open issues that still need to be implemented now:

- You need to implement a loop to apply the calculation above to each submatrix in the whole matrix (it will be two loops nested).
- You need to deal with the borders. usually, I think in image processing they want the result matrix to be of the same size as the input matrix. So you have to find a way to handle the areas where your kernel does overlap with areas that are not defined in the matrix anymore. E.g. when you want to set the value for field 0x0 in your example.
- You could create two distinct functions `apply_kernel_to_matrix` and `unique_values_kernel`, so that you could add more kernels later and just reuse the `apply_kernel_to_matrix` function later. Read about lambda functions for this.